# Why does Finder's scp folder disappear when ssh is invoked?

Tags: finder, filesystem

[sshfs 2.5 and fuse 3.8.3](https://osxfuse.github.io)  were installed on OS X 10.11.6 ElCapitan

Why does:

```
sshfs users@fqdn.com:/mnt/CRUZERFIT16/Directory /Users/user/Documents/scpbox
```

force the folder `scpbox` to disappear?  I would like to view the contents of the directory in the file manager 'Finder'.  The command:

```
ls -l /Users/user/Documents/scpbox
```

lists the contents of the remote Unix box.

What can be done to enable viewing in the file manager?  The remote Unix box has been tested with Ubuntu sshfs and is accessible through Ubuntu's native file manager (Nautilus).

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `-ovolname` option. Using your example:

```
sshfs users@fqdn.com:/mnt/CRUZERFIT16/Directory /Users/user/Documents/scpbox -ovolname=scpbox
```

Comment: Test results: scpbox did not disappear, however it did not show the directory's contents.  Attempts to exit and re-enter caused the directory to disappear.  Maybe I missed something?

Comment: mmhmmm… it definitively work for me. But I have sshfs 2.10 with osxfuse 3.8.2 which is more recent than your configuration. I installed it all with Homebrew.